# XML processors for executing xqj in java

Tags: java, xml, xquery

I need to query xml data using XQJ in my java application. I wanted to know the options that I have for xml/xquery processors.

I explored and got to know about:

1. oracle's xquery processor that is shipped with Oracle 11g
2. Saxon.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try BaseX, which also offers a full implementation of XQJ:

http://basex.org/products/
  http://docs.basex.org/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=xqj

You will most probably get better results when using the native APIs, no matter which processor you are using (but of course there are reasons for using XQJ as well).

Hope this helps,
Hannes

Comment: Hi Hannes, thanks a lot for the suggestion. I am new to xquery paradigm, can u please elaborate how can I invoke native xquery api from Java code? Performance is very important at what I am working.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dear SnoopyMe; I'm not an expert in programming with BaseX either, but the BaseX documentation was a good start for me:  http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Developing. The members of the project's mailing list seem to be very responsive as well. They might be glad to give you more hints): http://basex.org/open-source/

Answer (score 2):

You could certainly try MarkLogic, eXist, BaseX or Sedna XQJ drivers which are located at http://xqj.net

It would be daft to use vendor propriety APIs as you will be locked into a particular database vendor, with no improvement in performance.

Also you could try checking out the XQJ entry on Wikipedia for more clarity:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery_API_for_Java

Answer (score 2):

As well as having a processor you need an API. Charles Foster's XQJ.net might well help for
eXist, baseX, Sedna and Marklogic.

http://xqj.net/

Answer (score 1):

zorba has an [XQJ branch](https://code.launchpad.net/~rodolfo-ochoa/zorba/xqj). Please, consult the [zorba users mailing](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/zorba-users) list for further information on this.